# Incompatible Java Data Type

Tags: java, apache-flink

I'm building a Stream Processor using Apache Flink.

Simply put, I have no idea why this line:

```java
SingleOutputStreamOperator<VideoAdEvent> windowedStream = videoAdEventDataStream
    .windowAll(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)));
```

throws me this exception when I compile

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) W exist so that org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.AllWindowedStream<com.test.flink.videoadsinfluxsink.VideoAdEvent,W> conforms to org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.SingleOutputStreamOperator<com.test.flink.videoadsinfluxsink.VideoAdEvent>
```

Am I supposed to pass in `W` as an argument like: `SingleOutputStreamOperator<VideoAdEvent, W>` ? This seems to also throw me an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`windowAll` doesn't return a stream. Normally you would also specify how the window is to be processed, by calling `reduce`, `aggregate`, `apply`, or `process` on the result of `windowAll`, and in doing so, supply an appropriate function for processing the window's contents.

If you really want to capture the result of `windowAll` for some reason, it returns an `AllWindowedStream<T, W extends Window>`, so you would do that like this:

```java
AllWindowedStream<VideoAdEvent, TumblingEventTimeWindow> windowedStream ...
```